# Independent transactions in Spring JDBC

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, transactions

I'm using the *Spring JDBC* (`JdbcTemplate/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`) and Spring `TransactionManager` (`DataSourceTransactionManager`) in my DAO class.

I have at least 2 clients that simultaneously using DAO methods. Is it possible to open 2 definitely independent transactions with Spring JDBC/Tx, and use one separate transaction for every client?

Currently, using the **PROPAGATION_REQUIRED_NEW** parameter when creating the second transaction - I got only the nested transaction, i.e. it should be committed only before the first transaction.

Comment: Your question is not clear, because Spring opens completely independent transactions for different clients (i.e. different threads) by default. Can you show code?

Comment: Thank you! The issue was resolved: I wrote test that creates different DAO instances in one client thread - and got the nested transactions. When I put every client to its own thread - it works fine with fully independent transactions.

Comment: @K_K I know it has been a while, but could yous show some code snippet on how you got NamedParameterJdbcTemplate/DataSourceTransactionManager to work together. I am working on something similar and I like to verify if I am on right track.
So far, I assigned the same Datasource to the two NamedParameterJdbcTemplate/DataSourceTransactionManager object. However, I am confused how they are interacting with each other, as the code flow for the two are essentially independent of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Each of your two requests will have their own transaction context.

You can determine how serializable they are by setting the isolation level on your connection.